# XStream failing when & present in the XML document

Tags: parsing, xstream

I am using xStream for serializing and de-serializing objects. But when there is "&" present for any of the tag values , xStream is failing and throwing  excpetion.

for e.g. this fails..

```
<tag>value & value</tag>
Exception :- "An entity name must immediately follow..."

<tag>value value</tag>
this passes
```

Is there any way to tell xStream to ignore certain characters

Thanks!
Pratik

Comment: You're asking XStream to read something that isn't XML. Hardly surprising that it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's badly formed XML and any XML Parser (not just XStream) should fail that. The `&` should have been translated to `&amp;` on encoding (writing) the document.

I would identify what's writing that document and fix the character encoding, then any reading process should work ok.

Comment: xstream is converting &amp; to & when converting from xml to Java Objects. I don't want this to happen. How shall I do it?